# Reduce SQL queries Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have an endpoint that retrieves data from a get request.

My view:

```
class PricingCatalogLineViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = PricingCatalogLine
    permission_classes = (FullModelPermissions,)
    serializer_class = PricingCatalogLineSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination

    queryset = PricingCatalogLine.objects.select_related(
        'catalog_line__catalog', 'catalog_line', 'catalog_line__product'
    ).prefetch_related('catalog_line__catalog__catalog_buyers').all()

    filterset_class = PricingCatalogLineFiltersSet
    ordering_fields = ('catalog_line__name',)
    search_fields = ('catalog_line__name',)
    filter_backends = (
        filters.DjangoFilterBackend,
        OrderingFilter,
        SearchFilter,
    )

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        distributor_domain = CommunCodier.objects.get(
                collection='domaine_type',
                label='Distributeur'
            )
        return queryset.filter(
            catalog_line__catalog__catalog_buyers__entity=self.request.user.id,
            catalog_line__catalog__catalog_buyers__end_date__isnull=True,
            catalog_line__catalog__catalog_buyers__domain_type=distributor_domain.key)
```

results:

I have 1043 SQL queries done in 31000 ms...

I have this query which is done in a loop:

```
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [catalogue].[gts_id], [...] FROM [catalogue] WHERE [catalogue].[gts_id] = %s' - PARAMS = (1,)
```

`1000 similar queries.  Duplicated 30 times.`

I don't understand why I have so many SQL queries.

Do you have a solution to reduce the number of requests?

```
class PricingCatalogLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    _product = ProductSerializer(source='catalog_line.product')

    class Meta:
        model = PricingCatalogLine
        fields = ('_product', 'id', 'catalog_line', 'commitment', 'minimum_recurring', 'recurring',
                  'minimum_recurring_lease', 'recurring_lease', 'minimum_fas', 'fas',
                  'minimum_spread_fas', 'spread_fas', 'minimum_fas_lease', 'fas_lease',
                  'far', 'minimum_far', 'annual_licence_fee',
                  'minimum_annual_licence_fee', 'priority')
```

Comment: Can you share your `PricingCatalogLineSerializer`?

Comment: I edited my message

Comment: Can you also share your models? It could be that `ProductSerializer` is doing extra queries to build its data